# How do I access a calculated field in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

In my first attempt to develop something in Ruby on Rails :) ... I have a list of names stored in fields "first_name" and "last_name". In my Person model, I have defined something like this:

```
def sort_name
 sort_name = last_name + ',' + first_name
end
```

Now I want to show all persons shown in a list, sorted by sort_name, but (in my controller) something like

```
@persons = Person.order(:sort_name)
```

doesn't work (Unknown column 'sort_name' in 'order clause'). How do reference to the calculated field sort_name in my controller?
I am sure this is a "oh my god I am so stupid moment" but happy for any advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the model Person has the fields name, first_lastname and second_lastname, you can do the next:

```rb
Person.order(:name, :first_lastname, :second_lastname)
```

By default is ordering in ascending way. Also you can put if you want ascending or descending way for each field:

```rb
Person.order(name: :asc, first_lastname: :desc, second_lastname: :asc)
```

Additional if you want add a column with the complete name, you can use select, using postgresql the code would be:

```rb
people = Person.order(
  name: :asc, first_lastname: :desc, second_lastname: :asc
).select(
  "*, concat(name,' ', first_lastname, ' ',second_lastname) as sort_name"
)

people[0].sort_name
# the sort_name can be for example "Adán Saucedo Salas"
```

Comment: Thanks Andres, I got there already, but unfortunately in the long term it will not serve its purpose as the "sort_name" method ("calculated field") will evolve into something more complex. That was the whole idea - create a calculated field that I then later can access. Funny enough, it DOES work e. g. when I simply display it as e. g. part of an instance variable @arbitrary_person.sort_name ... so the question really is how to access it as part of the order method.

Comment: I have added in the answer other case where you can use a **select** to get a column with the _calculated field_

Comment: ok - I understand that code. But does that mean that adding the "sort_name" method in the people model actually doesn't serve any purpose?

Comment: No, it doesn't work, the method **order** receives a hash or string,  the hash/string must follow specific rules. When you tried to put a method **sort_name** it  is called before the method **order**,  then  the method ***sort_name** return a string and this string not follow the rules for order. The method **order** only sort the collection with people and not creates a specific field.

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful to know. I will try to find the documentation about the rules mentioned by you.